# Click an item in a drop-down menu using selenium Python library

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm trying to select an element in a drop-down menu. I tried to use "driver.find_element_by_xpath" call to locate the item in the list. The problem is that I can't select it. I tried ".click()" call but the error says that the element is not interactable. How can I select the item given the HTML code in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Please share the code that you tried.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: _I tried ".click()" call but the error says that the element is not interactable._ We need the code, and the entire error message. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Since the drop down menu is coded as "input" HTML tag traditional select Python method doesn't work as it works only with "select" HTML tag. But .send_keys method works just fine.  So a simple code bellow does the trick:

```
variable_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath of an <input> element in HTML code')
variable_name.click() #Clicks on the drop down button
variable_name.send_keys("text of an option in the drop down list") #sends text of an option in the drop down
```

Answer (score 0):

try this click on ul tag and then click on the dropdown li which you want to select.

Click on the dropdown and get li values if it comes using JS otherwise, you can direct click on li values which matched with your value

```
    element_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rcbList')))
   current_user_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element_dropdown)

    all_li_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rcbItem')))

    for single_li in all_li_dropdown:
        li_value = single_m_li.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        if li_value == "your_value":
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", single_li)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You should paste the code you use to help understand what you are doing.

But with only your explanation I'll say that you might need to click in the dropbox so the list is visible and clickable.

And then click in the item you want.

Python

```
driver.find_element_by_name('rcbScroll rcbWidth').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('rcbHovered').click()
```

Java

```
driver.findElement(By.className("rcbScroll rcbWidth")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("rcbHovered")).click();
```